# (perl Net::SMTP) authentication failure using gmail smtp server

Tags: perl, smtp, gmail

I have written a perl script to send email using the gmail's smtp server: smtp.gmail.com -

```
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('smtp.gmail.com',
                    Port=> 587,
                    Timeout => 20,
                    Hello=>'user@gmail.com'
                    );
print $smtp->domain,"\n";
$sender = "user@gmail.com";
$password = "mypassword";
$smtp->auth ( $sender, $password ) or die "could not authenticate\n";
$receiver = "user@gmail.com";

$subject = "my custom subject";
$smtp->mail($sender);
$smtp->to($receiver);
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: <$reciever> \n");
$smtp->datasend("From: <$sender> \n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/html \n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: $subject");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend('the body of the email');
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit();
print "done\n\n";
```

For 'user', I have my gmail username and for 'mypassword' I have the password. But when I run this code it stops at the auth itself giving : could not authenticate.

I am able to connect to the smtp serever of google as I get : 'mx.google.com' as the result of :
print $smtp->domain,"\n";

What is it that I am doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Net::SMTP;
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new ....
```

afaik you need to use an encrypted connection to send via gmail, use *Net::SMTP::TLS* or  *Net::SMTP::SSL* (with port 465)

```
Hello=>'user@gmail.com'
```

'Hello' is not an email address, put your hostname there instead

```
$sender = "user@gmail.com";
...
$receiver = "user@gmail.com";
```

put these in single quotes

if you still get "could not authenticate." make sure you have the modules *MIME::Base64* and *Authen::SASL* installed.

```
 $smtp->datasend("To: <$reciever> \n");
```

should be *$receiver*, not *$reciever*

Comment: I dropped the 'Hello' argument and corrected the quote mistakes, still no result. The TLS and SSL modules are available for perl 5.14 windows. I can't use it as I have to use win32::serialport as well in windows. Please tell some way to send it by tweaking the above code itself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "if you still get "could not authenticate." make sure you have the modules MIME::Base64 and Authen::SASL installed."

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses [TLS/STARTTLS on port 587, SSL on port 465](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=13287). Please follow [Sending email through Google SMTP from Perl](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2006/10/sending-email-through-google-smtp-from.html). Alternatively you could use [Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSend%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aGmail). I recommend this as it is way easier to use and has many more features.

Comment: I have to use win32::serialport as well which is unsupported in perl 5.14 in windows. The one you are referring is supported only for 5.14 in windows.